# Doing something after "redirect" in Cloud Function?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I would like to write to DB **after** i redirect a user:

```
 exports.contentServer = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
...
...
    return response.redirect(finalUrl + "front?action=" + action ) 
 
     .then(function(){   //  **** error : .then of undefined
        ....
```

I get an error in the promise.

```
Cannot read property 'then' of undefined
    at exports.contentServer.functions.https.onRequest
```

Comment: Please post the error you are getting here, also seems weird you are trying to redirect a user from a cloud function.

Comment: Thanks, i posted the error i get. Indeed i try to redirect user from a cloud function. is there a problem with it ?

Comment: It looks like `redirect` doesn't return a `Promise`.  The documentation also doesn't show any way to run more code *after* the redirection happens: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell `redirect` doesn't return a `Promise`.  In fact, from the `undefined` in your error message it seems like it doesn't return anything at all. The documentation also doesn't show any return value: https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.redirect

If it *were* to return something, you could capture that value and return it later:

```
const result = response.redirect(finalUrl + "front?action=" + action ) 

....

return result;
```

Comment: Thanks Frank, so how would one save something to DB before returning the page ? say i want to count visits.

Comment: I'd usually count before sending the response back to the caller.

Comment: Which makes the website load much slower, not just a little bit, but much more (?)

Comment: response.redirect is sending a response, which will definitely terminate the function immediately like response.send, as described in the documentation. https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/terminate-functions